# asp.net compiler error in generaed code

Tags: asp.net, compilation

I am about to go crazy about this. I tried to clean and rebuild, but I keep getting this error.

I have no Idea what to do about it.

What would you suggest?

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Error Message :

> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Intor32'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

in the file

```
Line 1:    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 2:    // <auto-generated>
Line 3:    //     This code was generated by a tool.
Line 4:    //     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18010
Line 5:    //
Line 6:    //Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
Line 7:    //     the code is regenerated.
Line 8:    // </auto-generated>
Line 9:    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
Line 10:   
Line 11:   using System;
Line 12:   using System.Web;
Line 13:   using System.Web.Profile;
Line 14:   
Line 15:   
Line 16:   
Line 17:   public class ProfileCommon : System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase {
Line 18:       
Line 19:       public virtual System.Intor32 OperatorId {
Line 20:           get {
Line 21:               return ((System.Intor32)(this.GetPropertyValue("OperatorId")));
Line 22:           }
Line 23:           set {
Line 24:               this.SetPropertyValue("OperatorId", value);
Line 25:           }
Line 26:       }
Line 27:       
Line 28:       public virtual ProfileCommon GetProfile(string username) {
Line 29:           return ((ProfileCommon)(ProfileBase.Create(username)));
Line 30:       }
Line 31:   }
Line 32:
```

It worked OK before, and I don't know what is that I changed.

I have no reference to Intor32 (searched the entire solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your `web.config` file at the `system.web/profile/properties` section. One of the `<add ... />` elements will have a `type="System.Intor32"` attribute. Change that to `type="System.Int32"` and everything should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

change `System.Intor32` to `System.Int32`, how was this file generated?